# Edge does not set height on canvas properly

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js, height, microsoft-edge

I just noticed strange behavior on Edge browser and I spent quite a lot of time to figure out what is going on. Looks like when you set width and height on canvas, then Edge will set only width attribute. Check following code:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
canvas.width = 1020;
canvas.height = 150;

var w = canvas.getAttribute('width'); // gets 1020
var h = canvas.getAttribute('height'); // gets null
```

Open following fiddle in Chrome/Edge.

https://jsfiddle.net/gmuy4j95/4/

Solution to this is to set the attribute manualy.

```
canvas.setAttribute('height', canvas.height);
```

I found this, because our ChartJs was not rendering correctly on Edge. But even the latest version of ChartJS uses getAttribute method. Can  someone explain to me what is going on? I did not find this as reported bug anywhere.

Comment: That would indeed be a bug but I really wonder why chartJS would use the HTML attribute rather than the DOM IDL property... What will they do with that string?

Comment: I opened ChartJS file from CDN and there is comment telling that if it is default, than the value is null - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.js (line 10617). However it works in Chrome.

Comment: I actually so it [there](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/b3d3df4239c37fa5d55c7b0ea08b71492f8e61ba/src/platforms/platform.dom.js) too. I didn't read really carefully, but it sounds they use it to see if the canvas size had been set to something else than the default and determine whether they should use their default values? Sounds like real bad design... You may want to open an issue to ChartJS about this test failing on Edge with the default sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the canvas size is 300 x 150, so when you set the height or width equal to the default size it gets overridden

So the below setting is of no use:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 150;

document.getElementById('width').innerHTML = canvas.getAttribute('width');
document.getElementById('height').innerHTML = canvas.getAttribute('height');
```

However, if you can set the height or width other than the default one then it should reflect and work in both Edge and Chrome.

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 1020;
canvas.height = 151;

document.getElementById('width').innerHTML = canvas.getAttribute('width');
document.getElementById('height').innerHTML = canvas.getAttribute('height');
```